# php variable in xml file between quotes

Tags: php, xml

`$string-i=5` for `id`, `$string-n=7` are `values`.

```
$output .= '<cat id="$string-i" name="$string-n"></cat>';
```

How can i write the variables between double quotes? xml result will be

```
<cat id="5" name="7"></cat>
```

Comment: You know XML allows single quotes too, right? `<cat id='5' name='7'></cat>` is well-formed XML. To output it, you can just swap the double quotes and single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**Concat operator:** The most apparent way is to use the concat operator `.`:

```
$output .= '<cat id="'.$string_i.'" name="'.$string_n.'"></cat>';
```

**Interpolation:** Another way is to use [string interpolation](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/The-Basics.html). If a string is enclosed in double-quotes (and only double-quotes work this way), you can reference the var right inside the string. Notice I escaped the quotes you want printed (`\"`) so that PHP doesn't treat them specially:

```
$output .= "<cat id=\"$string_i\" name=\"$string_n\"></cat>";
```

**Concat Assignment:** If, for some reason, you like sequential assignments:

```
$output .= '<cat id="';
$output .= $string_i;
$output .= '" name="';
$output .= $string_n;
$output .= '"></cat>';
```

**Notice:** I changed the string var names, as PHP vars can't contain dashes in their names. It might make more sense to name your vars `$id` and `$name`, or `$catId` and `$catName`. These are much clearer and easier to read and understand.

> Rules for PHP variables:
>
> 1. A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
> 2. A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
> 3. A variable name cannot start with a number
> 4. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
> 5. Variable names are case-sensitive ($age and $AGE are two different variables)

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$output = '<cat id="'.$string_i.'" name="'.$string_n.'"></cat>';
```

Comment: PHP does not allow '-' as in a variable name.